# How to identify scheduled reports that don't run?

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

We are running Cognos 11.0.1. There are times when scheduled reports don't run. This is an intermittent problem. I'd like to know if there is a way to identify these schedule reports that fail to run.

Answer (score 0):

This will show you all of the failures in the last 24 hours, when a report, dataset, agent, etc. was run, scheduled or interactive.  So, not exactly what you need, but it get you closer.

IBM Cognos Administration
Status
Past Activities
Period = Last 24 hours
Status = Failed

You can set Type if you want to see one, specific type of object.  Oddly, dataset is not an option.

If you have configured Cognos to audit to a database, you can also run a report against the Audit database.  COGIPF_RUNREPORT will likely get you most of what you want (reports, datasets, report views), but for [far more detail than you ever wanted] you should take a look at COGIPF_ACTION.  If you go this route, you should be able to combine the Audit results with results from a Content Store query that identifies which objects are scheduled.

Comment: It's not a matter of finding reports the "Failed" when the report  ran; it's a matter of trying to find reports that failed to run on the schedule. 
For example: Report X is schedule to run M-F at 7:30AM. 
Mon Success
Tue Fail
Wed Success
Fri Success

Thursday is missing. It was schedule to run on Thursday but never ran. 

How can I find out why and what caused the Thursday run to just get skipped?

Comment: Looking deeper... I see a failure from this morning, but COGIPF_ACTION shows success.  There are also rows that show failure (blank status) with references to that object in the error details, but not in the target path column.  So querying this way would be cumbersome at best.  So now I don't know where the data for the "past activities" page comes from.  Comparing successes to the schedules (and looking for gaps) can become challenging because of the way the schedule data is stored in the Content Store.  Maybe someone more experienced with Cognos administration tasks will answer.

Comment: Actually that makes sense.  If I didn't have an Audit database, the Past Activities page would still work.  And the data isn't coming from the logs because I can delete the logs and Past Activities still works.  More mysteries.  It's probably in the Content Store database somewhere, although I would expect that to bloat the database over time.

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-configure-audit-reporting-cognos-analytics

Comment: +∞ Thank you Doug. I'm going to delete the previous comment